# How to get Result from a clogit function as an output in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Hi i created a shiny app and i want to display my results from the clogit function in this app.

Bit I dont know where to start and how to display this list. I was thinking about to display the outcome of the console. But I have not found a solution yet

I want to results from this website to be displayed: http://lab.agr.hokudai.ac.jp/spmur/examples_ch3.R

```
clogit(fm, data = ds)

          coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z     p
ASC       0.027622  1.028007  0.041651  0.663 0.507
Green     0.027622  1.028007  0.058689  0.471 0.638
Brown     0.055239  1.056794  0.059322  0.931 0.352
Normal    0.027618  1.028003  0.058697  0.471 0.638
Muscular -0.027622  0.972756  0.058689 -0.471 0.638
Z        -0.001381  0.998620  0.002935 -0.471 0.638

Likelihood ratio test=2.28  on 6 df, p=0.8925
n= 5400, number of events= 2310
```

i want this result somehow to be displayed in the shiny app.

Can somebody provide me with an hint/ solution

Comment: Have you tried using the `broom` package to tidy the model outputs into a dataframe? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: thank you, that is what i was looking for